# Java multithreading confusing code snippet

Tags: java, multithreading

How should the code below perform if executed randomly at different time?

```
public class Unstoppable extends Thread {
    private int counter;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                counter++;

            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Unstoppable unStoppable = new Unstoppable();

        System.out.println("I am about to start");
        unStoppable.start();
        synchronized(unStoppable) {
            System.out.println("I was just told to wait");
            unStoppable.wait();
        }

        System.out.println(unStoppable.counter);
    }
}
```

At the first look at this it seemed like **it would hang infinitely** but quiety *surprisingly every time I execute this...It completes execution.*

Comment: you `wait` on a condition in loop. also `unstoppable unstoppable = new unstoppable();` does not follow proper naming convention for a class.

Comment: Meanwhile in a parallel universe...

Comment: Calling the class 'unstoppable` with all-lower-case is just wrong. Calling the instance the exact same name and case as the class is double-wrong.

Comment: Waits forever for me. What a waste of time!

Comment: it waits................

Comment: check now...the this updated code doesnt wait

Comment: Latest edit - Now you have commented out the synchronize block again... why?

Comment: Oh god I am tired of editing...you may check it now sincere apologies!

Comment: You trolling us? Now you have removed the Thread.sleep(10000), so it finishes..... this is a waste of time.

Comment: there is just one thread....increase number of threads and it will wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronization is meaningful if you have two or more threads. In your case there is just one thread.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Unstoppable unStoppable = new Unstoppable();
    Unstoppable unStoppable2 = new Unstoppable();
    Unstoppable unStoppable3 = new Unstoppable();
    System.out.println("I am bout to start");
    unStoppable.start();
    unStoppable2.start();
    unStoppable3.start();
    synchronized (unStoppable) {
        System.out.println("I was just told to wait");
        unStoppable.wait();
    }

    System.out.println(unStoppable.counter);
}

}
```

execute this at random times it might wait or try to increase the number of threads. By the way `wait` should be implemented like this.

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you ignoring exceptions somehow.... the code:

```
// synchronized(unstoppable) {
    System.out.println("I was just told to wait forever");
    unstoppable.wait();
// }
```

Should throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException`  and immediately exit.

---

EDIT

So you changed your code, and now it works the way you expect (it waits forever), so what's the problem? (I just tested it).

Comment: You are right, I had pasted the wrong snippet...corrected...now tell me?

Comment: and BTW @rolfl I know its the norm to put the wait in synchronized block but what is the thumb rule that validates this norm?

Comment: No rule-of-thumb, it's a language requirement (not a suggestion)... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

Comment: still...my question is why? even if language requirement, why?

Comment: See the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Answer (score 0):

> At the first look at this it seemed like it would hang infinitely but quiety surprisingly every time I execute this...It completes execution.

It completes because when a `Thread` finishes, there is a behind-the-scenes call to `thread.notify()`.  This is how `thread.join()` is implemented.

That said, it is not a good idea to depend on the code working in this manner -- or at least is should be labeled as a hack.  You should use `thread.join()` instead:

```
unStoppable.join();
```

Lastly, you should consider making your `Unstoppable` class implement `Runnable` instead of extending thread.  That's a better pattern:

```
public class Unstoppable implements Runnable {
...

Thread unStoppableThread = new Thread(new Unstoppable());
...
unStoppableThread.join();
```

Comment: his question has changed so many times that your answer, although it is correct for this version of the code, is not correct for the first number of versions. Specifically, in all but the last version of his question he had a `Thread.sleep(10000)` before the `wait()` which would essentially guarantee a 'forever' wait.

Comment: Yeah I saw that @rolfl.  I certainly didn't down vote your answer if that was the implied question.  :-)

Comment: Nah, downvoting does not phase me. I am really just annoyed that the OP has wasted lots of people's time by messing around with the question.... feels like he doesn't deserve it....

Comment: Agreed @rolfl.  I typically assume they don't know what they are doing wrong.  95% on SO don't realize that they should be asking/answering for posterity and not for their little pet issue.